# Unable to start hostednetwork in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, netsh

Output of command: `netsh wlan show drivers` is as below:

```
 Driver                    : Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
 Vendor                    : Intel Corporation
 Provider                  : Microsoft
 Date                      : 26-Mar-09
 Version                   : 12.4.1.4
 INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\netw5v32.inf
 Files                     : 1 total
                             C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\netw
 Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
 Radio types supported     : 802.11a 802.11b 802.11g
 FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
 **Hosted network supported  : No**
 Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                             Open            None
                             Open            WEP-40bit
                             Open            WEP-104bit
                             Open            WEP
                             Shared          WEP-40bit
                             Shared          WEP-104bit
                             Shared          WEP
                             WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                             WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                             WPA-Personal    TKIP
                             WPA-Personal    CCMP
                             WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                             WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                             WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                             Open            Vendor defined
 Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                             Open            None
                             Open            WEP-40bit
                             Open            WEP-104bit
                             Open            WEP
                             Shared          WEP-40bit
                             Shared          WEP-104bit
                             Shared          WEP
                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
```

the hosted network support is "No" which I need to turn to yes.
Also, I dont see microsoft virtual adapter in device manager anywhere.
I have allowed sharing of my modem connection.

But am unable to figure out how to enable internet sharing from my laptop.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

it was a driver problem, installed driver talent software and it automatically repaired and downloaded required missing drivers for hostednetwork to work.

thanks